# Cannot connect to network - Keeps asking for Password

Tags: wifi, networking

I recently tried to dual boot Elementary OS with Windows 7. I can see WiFi networks but when I try and connect to them, it asks for the password then tries to connect. After a while it stops and asks me the password again. I'm using a TP-LINK TL-WN881ND Wireless Adapter. Thanks for all your help in advance. Tell me if you need any other information.

Update: What terminal says after `sudo lshw -C network`

```
 elementary@elementary:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: e8:94:f6:fb:2b:ff
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.19.0-39-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:32 memory:fe800000-fe80ffff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 06
   serial: 74:d4:35:99:77:fd
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:29 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe700000-fe700fff memory:d0000000-d0003fff
 elementary@elementary:~$
```

Comment: What if you type the key phrase in a text editor and then select & paste it in the wireless password dialogue box?

Comment: Tried that, it still keeps on asking me for the password.

Comment: That wireless adapter use the Ath9k driver, supported in elementary-os and Ubuntu derivates by default. Type the next command and copy&paste the output: sudo lshw -C network

Comment: Please edit to add `iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|cipher'` and post what one you are trying to connect to

Answer (score 1):

Try System Settings/Network/Wireless/click on your wireless network.
go to Settings/wi-fi security/ and double check that your password has been entered and spelled correctly,perhaps re-entering it and manually saving.